# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.+ Install Repository and sync project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

[image]

I was working day before yesterday. Suddenly showed this error when I clean my project.
I'm not able to compile my project. What should I do?

It is giving me this error while trying to Install Repository.

[image]

Comment: You should do what Studio tells you to do; Install Repository and sync project again. After that, do you still got the error?

Comment: Added more clarity to the question. Is is possible to use the 7.0 version of the google play services plus ?

Comment: @WhatsTools Update your SDK Manager

Answer (score 1):

Just click install repository and sync project.

Android studio will download the repository you miss to compile your project and will add it to your project.

Comment: I've tried to do it, but giving me some error message. I've added it to my question